# Array indexes to wide for array

Tags: arrays, indexing, vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

I have the following problem when accessing arrays in VHDL:

Say I have an array which is not of size 2^n, for example of size 6.
Then, if I want to access this array using an index of width 3 bits (=ceil(log2(6))), it is clear that this index can reach two positions, 7 and 8, which are beyond the size of the array I am accessing. Xilinx ISE gives me a warning in this case.

How should I go about this? My possible solutions are as follows:

1.) Ignore the warnings. Hope synthesis is smart.

2.) Only use arrays of size 2^n. Hope unused portions of array will be optimized away.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to ignore the warnings in this case. Synthesis can handle this.

Synthesis can also easily optimize away anything not used, but artificially increasing array sizes seems like overkill.

Comment: Just a thought: could you just use an "integer range 0 to 5"  instead of a 3-bit vector. This might make the simulator happy, and give clear hints to the synthesis tool for optimization.

Comment: @Philippe The simulator would be equally happy or unhappy (in terms of run-time errors) for both cases. But a constrained integer is indeed a more direct way to express the intent.